# How to call Bing Maps REST service using NuGet Bing.RestClient

Tags: c#, json, rest, bing-maps

I want to use NuGet called Bing.RestClient v0.8 beta 1, in Visual Studio 2017, but I have no clue how to use it in Windows Forms to get Location (Latitude/Longitude).

I am not familiar with REST services yet.

Any code example that can help me to structure the project and understand how it works?

I have tried with a web client and I can get the TEXT response that I may parse, but I want to use the classes available in the NuGet `Bing.RestClient`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // PERSONAL BING KEY
    String BingKey = "*******************************";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetFind();
    }

    private async void  GetFind()
    {

        // Take advantage of built-in Point of Interest groups
        var list = PoiEntityGroups.Government();
        list.Add(PoiEntityTypes.Bank);
        // Build your filter list from the group.
        var filter = PoiEntityGroups.BuildFilter(list);
        var client = new Bing.SpatialDataClient(BingKey);

        //---------------------------------------------------------
        // This does NOT use the Nuget but just a WebClient and I get the response in TEXT format. But this is not what I want.
        String AddressQuery = "Via Ravenna 10, Milano";
        String BaseQueryURL;
        BaseQueryURL = String.Format("http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query={0}?maxResults=1&key={1}", AddressQuery, BingKey);

        // Create web client simulating IE6.
        using (System.Net.WebClient wclient = new WebClient())
        {
            wclient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (Compatible; Windows NT 5.1; MSIE 6.0)";

            byte[] arr = wclient.DownloadData(BaseQueryURL);
            txtResult.Text = "Bytes: " + arr.Length + Environment.NewLine;
            txtResult.Text = txtResult.Text + wclient.DownloadString(BaseQueryURL);
        }
        //---------------------------------------------------------
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to get the result deserialized by using the NuGet classes, but I don't know how to use them to get my Latitude and Longitude, querying by address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you review the examples provided on the GitHub page for the BingMapsRESTToolkit NuGet package. (https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit/blob/master/Docs/Getting%20Started.md#HowToMakeARequest)

Here is a basic example from the GitHub that I got working in Visual Studio as a console app:

```
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var bingKey = "**********************";

        var request = new GeocodeRequest()
        {
            Query = "Via Ravenna 10, Milano",
            IncludeIso2 = true,
            IncludeNeighborhood = true,
            MaxResults = 25,
            BingMapsKey = bingKey
        };

        //Process the request by using the ServiceManager.
        var response = await request.Execute();

        if (response != null &&
            response.ResourceSets != null &&
            response.ResourceSets.Length > 0 &&
            response.ResourceSets[0].Resources != null &&
            response.ResourceSets[0].Resources.Length > 0)
        {
            var result = response.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0] as Location;

            var coords = result.Point.Coordinates;
            if (coords != null && coords.Length == 2)
            {
                var lat = coords[0];
                var lng = coords[1];
                Console.WriteLine($"Geocode Results - Lat: {lat} / Long: {lng}");
            }
        }
    }
```

From this, you now have a pair of lat/long as type Double.  Use them in your Windows Form as you see fit.

Comment: It looks like you are calling functions from a different Bing NuGet(?) that has "bing.geocode.GeocodeService", but the NuGet I have installed gives me the following options only: Bing.Core, Bing.Maps and Bing.Spatial. What am I mistaking?

Comment: I have found it in "BingMapsRESTToolkit" NuGet. Nobody told me this before ... Well, hope I can work it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Bryan for your precious example. 
Finally I've got it working very fine in this way, in Windows Forms:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // PERSONAL BING KEY
        String BingKey = "*******************************";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetFind();
        }

        private async void GetFind()
        {    
            var request = new GeocodeRequest()
            {
                Query = "Via trento 1, Sondrio",
                IncludeIso2 = true,
                IncludeNeighborhood = true,
                MaxResults = 25,
                BingMapsKey = BingKey
            };


            //Process the request by using the ServiceManager.
            var response = await request.Execute();

            if (response != null &&
                response.ResourceSets != null &&
                response.ResourceSets.Length > 0 &&
                response.ResourceSets[0].Resources != null &&
                response.ResourceSets[0].Resources.Length > 0)
            {
                var result = response.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0] as Location;

                var myAddr = result.Address.AddressLine;
                var CAP = result.Address.PostalCode;
                var City = result.Address.Locality;
                var Province = result.Address.AdminDistrict2;
                var Region = result.Address.AdminDistrict;
                var Stato = result.Address.CountryRegion;

                var coords = result.Point.Coordinates;
                if (coords != null && coords.Length == 2)
                {
                    var lat = coords[0];
                    var lng = coords[1];

                    string Latitude = String.Format("{0:00.000000}", lat);
                    string Longitude = String.Format("{0:000.000000}", lng);

                    txtResult.Text = "Indirizzo: " + myAddr +
                        Environment.NewLine + "CAP: " + CAP +
                        Environment.NewLine + "Città: " + City +
                        Environment.NewLine + "Provincia: " + Province +
                        Environment.NewLine + "Regione: " + Region +
                        Environment.NewLine + "Stato: " + Stato + 
                        Environment.NewLine + $"Coordinate - Lat: {Latitude} / Long: {Longitude}"
                        ;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you got it working.  I would appreciate it if you would mark my Answer as correct.